# GetAsyncKeyState from windows.h

Tags: winapi

I will use the following code to explain my question:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool toggle = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState('C') & 0x8000)
        {
            toggle = !toggle;
            if (toggle) std::cout << "Pressed\n";
            else std::cout << "Not pressed\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Testing, I see that

```
(GetAsyncKeyState('C') & 0x8000) // 0x8000 to see if the most significant bit is 1
```

has the same behavior as

```
(GetAsyncKeyState('C'))
```

However, to achieve the behavior I want, which is the way any text input out there works (it waits like 1 second, and if you are still pressing the button, it starts spamming in a certain rate), I need to write

```
(GetAsyncKeyState('C') & 1)
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx) says

> The behavior of the least significant bit of the return value is retained strictly for compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications (which are non-preemptive) and should not be relied upon.

Can someone clarify this please?

Comment: *"which is the way any text input out there works"* - Wrong. Any reliable text input implementation uses the synchronous character messages, as a result of calling `TranslateMessage`. You have opted for the wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention I intended to replicate the typing on a .txt document or a google search bar

Comment: Typing in Notepad is implemented using the synchronous character messages. If you are interested to find out, how Google Chrome implements text input, you can read its source code. I would be surprised if it didn't use synchronous character messages as well. It's unclear how you propose to inject input using keyboard state retrieval API's.

Comment: Why not create a Windows program with an edit control?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN tells you why on the same page you linked to!

> Although the least significant bit of the return value indicates whether the key has been pressed since the last query, **due to the pre-emptive multitasking nature of Windows, another application can call GetAsyncKeyState and receive the "recently pressed" bit instead of your application**. The behavior of the least significant bit of the return value is retained strictly for compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications (which are non-preemptive) and should not be relied upon.

`GetAsyncKeyState` gives you "the interrupt-level state associated with the hardware" and is probably shared by all processes in the window station/session.

The low bit might be connected to the keyboard key repeat delay you can set in Control Panel, but it does not really matter because MSDN tells you to not look at that bit.

`GetAsyncKeyState` is usually not the correct way to process keyboard input. Console applications should read stdin, or use the console API. GUI applications should use the `WM_CHAR`/`WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP` window messages.

Comment: But if MSDN tells me not to look at that bit, how else would I achieve that behaviour?

Comment: See the bottom of my answer. Don't use GetAsyncKeyState.

Comment: `Get[Async]KeyState` doesn't consume input. If you want to take immediate reactions in console application, you can switch off input processing with `SetConsoleMode`. Check aloso `ReadConsoleInput`.